# MVCSitemap Nodes not Rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I have installed the MvcSiteMap provider and have a basic sitemap defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" enableLocalization="true">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Borrower" controller="Borrower" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Sign Up" controller="Borrower" action="Create"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Investor" controller="Investor" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Sign Up" controller="Investor" action="Create"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Dealer" controller="Dealer" action="Index">  
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Sign Up" controller="Dealer" action="Create"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

My HomeController:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Veehco.Models;
    using Telerik.Web.Mvc;

```
namespace Veehco.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    VeehcoEntities _db;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _db = new VeehcoEntities();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to Veehco!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MenuPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Shared/MenuPartial");
    }   
}

public partial class MenuController : Controller
{
    [PopulateSiteMap(SiteMapName = "Veehco", ViewDataKey = "Veehco")]

    public ActionResult SiteMapBinding()
    {
        if (!SiteMapManager.SiteMaps.ContainsKey("Veehco"))
        {
            SiteMapManager.SiteMaps.Register<XmlSiteMap>("Veehco", sitemap => sitemap.LoadFrom("~/Veehco.sitemap"));
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Orientation(string orientation) 
    { 
        ViewData["orientation"] = orientation ?? "Horizontal"; 
        return View(); 
    }

    public ActionResult AnimationEffects(string animation, bool? enableOpacityAnimation, int? openDuration, int? closeDuration)
    { 
        ViewData["animation"] = animation ?? "slide"; 
        ViewData["enableOpacityAnimation"] = enableOpacityAnimation ?? true; 
        ViewData["openDuration"] = openDuration ?? 200; ViewData["closeDuration"] = closeDuration ?? 200; 
        return View(); 
    }
}
}
```

When I build and view this site, only the About and Contact links are visible.  How do I setup my sitemap and/or HomeController to display the other top level and sub nodes?

Thansk much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you only want to have one `mvcSiteMapNode` element at the root of the `mvcSiteMap`.  Try putting Borrower, Investor, and Dealer within your Home element (at the same level as About and Contact).